# Distance between two points with an stimated time.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I am working on a project and one problem is this:
I have two points, $A$ and $B$, but the only thing I Know is, time.
with a time I want a distance between $2$ points, I want to calculate meters...
So if my time is $5.0$s 
I wanna know distance and velocity...
Is there any way to do it?
Using complex numbers or real.

Comment: I am sorry, but question is not clear.

Comment: @WinVineeth You have two points , and only know the time of the path that was from one point to another , like knowing the distance between the two points knowing only tim

Comment: Well, If we know at least the velocity, we can calculate. If we know only time, I am sry but we can't know the distance.

Answer (score 0):

Say that the distance between your points is x and the time it takes you to travel that distance is t, also assume a constant velocity of v=x/t. You need to know the velocity as well as the time to know the distance or else the above equality is satisfied for many different v and t.  The problem is harder if one considers that the velocity between the two points is non constant.  does this make sense?